# I am stuck on this electromagnetism concept

Tags: electric-fields, polarization, boundary-conditions, dielectric

Does $\mathbf{D}$ depend on the medium or not? If not, then why does the tangential component of $\mathbf{D}$ change across the boundary of two dielectrics with different relative permittivity when we solve the boundary condition between the two surfaces?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the medium. D is the displacement field, and is the field generated by displaced charges within the medium. In some media, charges are displaced more easily than in others.
This can relate either to slightly displaced orbitals, or like in the case of metals, to fluid charges.
Since in a metal, for example, the charges move freely, they can exactly cancel out the applied electric field. Thus, the permittivity, takes the value -1.
Think of the displacement field of "what's left after the electric field interacted with the medium".

The displacement field is also intuitively frequency dependent. It changes with frequency, because it very much is a material dependent quantity.